# Saving files inside a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

I've read every question and answer on this topic I can find on this site (and others) and still cannot find answers for the following scenario.

I have a SQL Server 2008R2 hosted in a data center. My client is using my Windows application that stores data in a SQL Server 2008R2 database. There are Word, Excel, PDF, JPG, PNG, etc documents that are linked to records in the database. My client needs to have access to these docs from anywhere.

My thinking is that I will save the docs into the database records, thus making them available from anywhere.

My questions are:

1. Am I correct in assuming that if the hosting provider has not turned on FileStream on SQL Server, then I cannot use that facility on my own databases? (This seems like a reasonable assumption but maybe someone can confirm this is not available on an individual database level.)
2. Am I correct in assuming that the hosting provider will also have to allow read/write to a folder structure if I decide to save files directly to disk?
3. Finally, can anyone provide comment on their real-life experiences with saving documents in a "cloud-hosted" SQL Server database. Is performance going to be a technical issue to overcome or simply one of trying users' patience?

Thanks for you help and insights.

Comment: "My client need to have access to these docs from anywhere". I have experience using both Azure Blob Storage and Amazon S3 for file storage and its better to use those and save the URL references into your database. You can always protect these files from being directly accessed and enable the user of the system to download these files on demand via signing them. There is tons of docs on this. Why are you using a windows app? Seems perfect for a website solution.

Comment: The WinApp is an existing product that provides functionality simply not possible in a WebApp (ATM). A web UI is being developed but that will not change the underlying functionality of the solution. This is the first client using this particular product of ours that has requested this "docs from anywhere" functionality, but I can see this being demanded by other clients so I want to get it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, you are not correct. You can still stream files in/out of the database otherwise, just without the ability to use direct file-like URLs which are served by the database itself.
2. Yes. Almost all do, though.
3. Done reasonably, there's no reason it can't work just fine for all but the most extreme performance-critical situations. which is not the same thing as saying that's how you should do it.

Comment: To add to point #3, usually SQL space is significantly more expensive than just straight up cloud storage, so your costs may be unnecessarily high if you are storing a lot of files in the DB.

Comment: That's a good point @JohnKoerner ; since you typically pay for cloud storage by the byte, that's something to keep in mind.

Comment: I see that I have been misleading with my terms ("cloud", etc). The SQL database is currently hosted and space/cost is not my issue. (The client is receiving sponsorship for his hosting/SQL costs from the  hosting provider). Having said that, it raises a flag for me to check this out further for any future sites.

Comment: @Chimesy Ahh, good enough. The term `cloud` is a nebulous one (pun intended) for sure, but it usually does denote something more than 'hosted externally'. If the space is not a problem, that would be one less objection to using it that way.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Full marks for a succinct and clear answer. I am new to stackoverflow and the support is absolutely fantastic.

Comment: @Chimesy Thank you! You asked a question that has been asked a *lot* of times, but you did so with enough specificity that it definitely seemed worth answering.